How can I avoid duplicating multi-column correlated subqueries?
I want a correlated sub query that returns multiple columns and filters itself based on values in the main table.
A list of student test scores for a set of days:
create table student
(id, name     ); insert into student values
(1 , 'joe'    ),
(2 , 'steve'  );

create table testScore
(id, studentId, day  , score); insert into testScore values
(1 , 1        , 5    , 70   ),
(2 , 1        , 10   , 68   ),
(3 , 1        , 15   , 95   ),
(4 , 1        , 20   , 81   ),
(5 , 2        , 5    , 100  ),
(6 , 2        , 10   , 75   ),
(7 , 2        , 15   , 98   ),
(8 , 2        , 20   , 92   );
create index testScore_studentTopScores on testScore (studentId, score, day);

If I need to get the top test score for each student (and include the corresponding day numbers, and have the testScore_studentTopScores index be used) I would love to do:
select
  student.name,
  topScore.score as topScore,
  topScore.day as topScoreDay
from
  student
  left join (
    select * from
      testScore
    where
      testScore.studentId = student.id
    order by
      score desc
    limit 1
  ) as topScore
order by
  topScore desc;

And have it return:



name
topScore
topScoreDay




steve
100
5


joe
95
15



But from clause subqueries can't reference outer/parent tables. Column subqueries and where clause subqueries are able to access tables in the from clause, but cannot return multiple columns. So I have to duplicate the subquery for every column:
select
  student.name,

  (
    select
      score
    from
      testScore
    where
      testScore.studentId = student.id
    order by
      score desc
    limit 1
  )  as topScore,

  (select day from (
    select
      score,
      day
    from
      testScore
    where
      testScore.studentId = student.id
    order by
      score desc
    limit 1
  ))  as topScoreDay

from
  student
order by
  topScore desc;

Neither SQLite nor MySQL can do this without duplication for each column. Microsoft SQL Server has an outer apply join operator; like a left join but where the clause can reference prior tables in the from clause. That's what I want in SQLite.
Also, the solution should not be an SQL trick to just handle this simple example. It needs to be general enough to be scalable for any large and complex query.

As an aside, I now realize that MySQL does also support this feature via the lateral join operator since v8.0.14 in Jan. 2019, however MariaDB still does not in Oct 2024. MariaDB issue

According to this answer from Database Administrators SQLite only disallows access to outer tables when directly joining subqueries. It does allow access to outer tables inside subqueries that are part of on clauses.
I'm using a "CORRELATED SCALAR SUBQUERY" according to EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN, which allows access to the current row of the parent student table. No need to use limit 1 in the subquery because SQLite returns only the first row to satisfy the on clause.
select
  student.name,
  testScore.score as topScore,
  testScore.day as topScoreDay
from
  student
  left join testScore on testScore.id = (
    select id from
      testScore
    where
      testScore.studentId = student.id
    order by
      score desc
  )
order by
  topScore desc;


You can left join with the top score of the student and left join with an even better score and filtering out any tuple which has a better score for even better:
select
  student.name,
  topScore.score as topScore,
  topScore.day as topScoreDay
from
  student
  left join testScore as topScore
  on topScore.studentId = student.id
  left join testScore as evenBetterScore
  on topScore.studentId = evenBetterScore.studentId and topScore.score < evenBetterScore.score
where evenBetterScore.studentId is null
order by
  topScore.score desc;

so you will end up having a single record for each student, along with the top score of the student if it exists.

Thanks for this, it's a pretty neat solution. I'm not sure about the efficiency though... At first glance it seems like it will have to compare each test score against all of the other test scores for that student.  Maybe the index will help there and optimize that...  But in any case, it would also mean that if there was a complicated where clause for selecting the test scores, like where topScore.score >= 75 and topScore.day > 5, it would need to be duplicated for evenBetterScore.

@BillF. if you have an index on score then the join will not have serious performance issues. And indeed, if you have further criteria, then it needs to be applied for evenBetterScore like you correctly said. Yet, if you have an index on the score and possibly other attributes, depending on your needs, then you can check the query plan, which will likely filter on the indexed fields first, so the other criterias will be unlikely to cause much trouble performance-wise.

This particular query can be solved by computing the row_number() over partition by studentId order by score desc and then doing a left join it with when the row number = 1. I've extracted that part into a CTE for clarity but you can put it directly inside the left join if needed:
with testScoreWithRowNumber as (
  select *, row_number() over (partition by studentId order by score desc) as rn
  from testScore
)
select 
  s.name,
  r.score as topScore,
  r.day as topScoreDay
from student s
left join testScoreWithRowNumber r on r.studentId = s.id and r.rn = 1
order by r.score desc;

Output:
name,topScore,topScoreDay
steve,100,5
joe,95,15


Thanks for the response.  I think it's a clever solution, but there is one aspect that I don't like, which is that the testScoreWithRowNumber "temp table" needs to be precalculated completely for all students first.  So if I only want to select the results for a handfull of students, it would be less efficient.  And I may not know the studentIds ahead of time, but would rather filter the outer student query by some other columns in the student table. (Like all student names that begin with 'J'),  Granted, I failed to mention this requirement in the OP, sorry about that.

Efficient because it only needs one lookup for each student; jam columns I want into one JSON column and extract them later:
select
  topScore.name,
  topScore.topScoreJson ->> 'score' as topScore,
  topScore.topScoreJson ->> 'day' as topScoreDay
from (
  select
    student.name,
    (
      select
        json_object(
          'score', testScore.score,
          'day', testScore.day
        )
      from
        testScore
      where
        testScore.studentId = student.id
      order by
        testScore.score desc
      limit 1
    ) as topScoreJson
  from
    student
) as topScore
order by
  topScore desc;


On SQLite (non-standard SQL), the answer is much more simple ;
SELECT s.name, MAX(t.score) as topScore, t.day AS topScoreDay
FROM student as s
LEFT JOIN testScore AS t ON s.id = t.studentId
GROUP BY s.id
ORDER BY topScore DESC, t.score ASC;

Result :



name
topScore
topScoreDay




steve
100
5


joe
95
15



MAX() aggregate function coupled with GROUP BY clause keep the highest value for each student (student.id).
And ORDER BY clause sort the result.

This works only on SQLite because GROUP BY coupled with MAX() aggregate function isn't possible on standard SQL. But SQLite understand perfectly how to treat this query.
